# How do I make remove the "tufts" and get this to be better rounded?

Tags: modeling

I have a model I'm making, with a mirror modifier and a subdivision surfaces modifier in use, where an ear has "tufts". How do I remove these "tufts" and make the edges connecting the ear to the head uniformly rounded, rather than hap-hardly rounded?

Here's an image of the ear's topology:
[image]

Here's the ear in object mode.
[image]

I've tried moving around the points manually, but that only makes it worse. I've tried scaling it on the y axis, but that doesn't help, either, because all the points, underneath the subdivision surfaces modifier, are in a line nice curved line, anyway. I've also tried subdividing the mesh then decimating it, but collapse, unsubdivide and planar ruin the mesh and planar makes a "tuft" worse.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Your topology looks quite messy. I see triangles, Ngons unconnected vertex and zero sized faces. You should strive for clean topology, with a mostly quad based topology, with an occasional triangle, and good edge-flow

Comment: Thank you. I started again without using the Boolean modifier or using knife project to create holes and it looks better now. I'm still new to modeling.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid using polygons with more than 4 edges(except on hard flat non deforming surfaces)....that is where your issues are coming from...there are no edges for the subdivisions to adhere to.